# Java don't see the file

Tags: java, android, enoent

`MainActivity:

`    package com.example.game;

```
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.HashMap;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public Database db = new Database();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);


        // inizializating varibales
        db.main();
    }
}`
```

Database:

```
`package com.example.game;

import java.lang.Exception;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Database {

    public static void main(){
        try {

            FileReader fr = new FileReader("user.txt");
            fr.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}``
```

I'm tried to add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to android manifest

Then I'm tried to check files in my dir by MainActivity program and it shows nothing.

Comment: Could you add some more detail regarding what you are trying to do and any errors that you're receiving?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not defined the path

```
try {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("user.txt");
        fr.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> user.txt

instead you should use like

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("/sdcard/Downloads/user.txt");
```

or the main path where user.txt exists

Hope it Helps!

Comment: how to get this main path?

Comment: nothing helped I tried this

Comment: FileReader fr = new FileReader("/data/user/0/com.example.game/files/user.txt");

Comment: On the new android versions you cannot easily write wherever you want ... permissions are much stricter now ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, you might enter the path like `/data/data/(package name)/files/your_file.txt` or enter other path to app storage.

Comment: if you are using files dir then you dont need the read_external and write_external permission just use context.getFilesDir()